# mysql count children of selected rows having selected rows as parent?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, recursive-query

Table structure(representative)

```
ID   NAME     PARENT
--------------------
1    cat1     0
2    cat1     1
3    cat2     1
4    cat1     2
5    cat2     2
6    cat3     2
7    cat1     3
8    cat2     3
9    cat3     3
10    cat1    1
```

FOREIGN TABLE data for foreign_sub_category_count

```
    id_parent   name
-----------------------
    2            a
    2            b
    2            c
    3            a
    3            b
    3            c
```

categories may have sub categories.

```
SELECT t.name,t.id
FROM TABLE_NAME AS t
WHERE t.parent = SOME_ID
```

SOME_ID = 1
gives me the name,id of all categories with SOME_ID parent id

what i want is to get a count of all sub categories of each row in above result set besides the name 
WHERE t.id is parent of sub categories and get count of categories from another table which has the same t.id as parent

EXPECTED RESULT

```
t.id   t.name  sub_category_count  foreign_sub_category_count
2       cat1         3                        3
3       cat2         3                        3
10      cat1         0                        0
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: And where do those numbers come from?  You have counts of "10" in your desired results, but have only seven rows in your data.

Comment: its just representative, my original table is quite extensive

Comment: @GordonLinoff is this possible in MYSQL without recursive query ?

Comment: . . I can't figure out what you are really asking for without clearer data.  GMB has pretty well-thought out answers to questions and is suggesting a recursive CTE so that seems like a likely solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have edited the data, is it better now ?

Comment: from where you want to get the details of `foreign_sub_category_count` column data

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are looking for a recursive query - available in MySQL 8.0:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select id root_id, id from mytable
    union all
    select c.root_id, t.id from cte c inner join mytable t on t.parent = c.id
)
select 
    t.*,
    (select count(*) - 1 from cte c where c.root_id = t.id) no_children
from mytable t
```

This adds one column to your original table, which contains the number of direct and indirect descendants of the current row.

Comment: i do not have access to this version

Comment: is this possible in MYSQL without recursive query ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
tab1.id, 
tab1.name, 
coalesce(tab2.counts,0) as sub_category_count,
coalesce(tab3.counts,0) as foreign_sub_category_count
from 

(select id,name,parent from representative) tab1

left join 

(select t1.parent tab_id, count(*) as counts  from representative t1 inner join representative t2 on t1.parent=t2.id group by t1.parent) tab2
on tab1.id=tab2.tab_id

left join 

(select parent_id,count(*) as counts from foreign_table group by parent_id) tab3 

on tab1.id=tab3.parent_id

where tab1.parent=1 --SOME_ID
```

you can change the parent_id in `where tab1.parent=1` of you choice

 
Example on [DB-FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2cs9uMQcUDFfwkCcPyS4G9/5)